# PHP Exec() Using Sed Gives Strange Results

Tags: php, sed

I have a list of full file paths. All of the full file paths look like "/dir1/dir2/dir3/s..". I want to completely remove the s. from the filename. There is the possibility of a filename being plural, for example s.asdfs.cpp. I do not want to remove the second occurence of s. since that is part of the actual filename and not a reoccuring theme in every full file path in the list.

Running the following in shell works as I want it to:

```
echo /dir1/dir2/dir3/s.filenames.cpp | sed 's#\(.*\)\/s\.\([^\/]*\)#\1\/\2#g'
```

Gives the desired result of:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/filenames.cpp
```

But if I run the following in php:

```
$formatted_filename = exec("echo ".$filename." | sed 's#\(.*\)\/s\.\([^\/]*\)#\1\/\2#g'");
```

where

```
$filename = /dir1/dir2/dir3/s.filenames.cpp;
```

And then in my bash shell run

```
php -q script_name_that_contains_command_above.php > test.html
```

and refresh my firefox browser that displays test.html I get very strange results. In place of where this edited file path should be listed I get

```
<strange box>/<strange box>
```

where

```
<strange box>
```

is a small box with 2 rows and 2 columns consisting of 0's except for the bottom right cell. The first occurence has a 1 in the bottom right cell, and the second occurence has a 2 in the bottom right cell.

The sed command works, but php, or the exec command is interpreting it incorrectly I believe. Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you use php's regular expressions?

Comment: I am pretty new to PHP. Are you suggesting the preg_match function?

Comment: That "strange box" is probably an "unknown character" font glyph, for unprintable characters. Probably a null (ascii 0).

Comment: You might change: `"echo ".$filename."` to `"echo \".${filename}.\"`

Comment: Taking a weird shot at this (null char sounds likely too), what you describe as a small box, could that be some crazy interpretation of the '#' char? Try changing your reg-ex delimiters to '@'. If you get a different failure, then that's a clue. If it works, then that is even better ;-) Good luck.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but nothing has worked so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for using exec with this particular regular expression was to use the php function, [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
preg_replace("/\/s/./", "/", $filename);
```